# URL in Yii2 GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

I have this code:

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
       'label' => 'bla',
       'format' => 'url',
       'value' => function ($data) {
            return Html::url('site/index');
       },
    ],
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
  ],
]); ?>
```

In grid view text is being generated with URL address.

```
/academia-new/advanced/admin/site/index
```

URL is working fine, but how can I set a text for link?

Comment: you may want to accept one of the answers as the correct one...? ;)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `'format' => 'raw'` instead of  `'format' => 'url'`.

Comment: what if you want to send some data with it lets say an integer .. and how would to retrieve it in controller ??

Comment: [
    'attribute' => 'invoice_id',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {
     return Html::a($model->invoice_id, [
      'invoice/view',
      'id' => $model->invoice_id
     ], ['target' => '_blank']);
    },
   ],

Answer (score 27):

I got the solution from Samdark, contributor of yii. need to use format=>'raw':

```
...    
'format' => 'raw',
     'value'=>function ($data) {
        return Html::a(Html::encode("View"),'site/index');
    },
```

need to use Html::encode() to ecape XSS

Answer (score 10):

solution:

```
<?=  GridView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'filterModel' => $searchModel,
       'columns' => [
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
             [
             'label'=>'bla',
             'format' => 'raw',
             'value'=>function ($data) {
                        return Html::a(['site/index']);
                      },
             ],
     ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
  ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Some intentation would really help the readability of your answer

Comment: return Html::a(['site/index']) do not work in yii2 -> error, try return Html::a('link','site/index');

Answer (score 5):

use raw format

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
           'label'=>'url',
           'format' => 'raw',
       'value'=>function ($data) {
            return Html::a('there is your label',['site/index']);
        },
    ],
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
return Html::a('link_text','site/index');
```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php

Answer (score 3):

I think I got the solution:

The code:

```
'value'=>function ($data) {
        return Html::url('site/index');
    },
```

Should be a bit modified. Let say your field name in array 'country', then code should be like this:

```
'value'=>function ($data) {
        return Html::a($data['country'], ['site/index']);
    },
```

So instead of *Html::url* I used *Html::a* and added value of the hyperlink as *$data['country']*.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this one if you need to make the attribute as label :

```
[
 'label'=>'' ,
 'header'=>Yii::t('app', 'Sample Number'),
 'attribute'=>'sample_number',  
                  'width'=>'310px',
                  'value' => function ($model) {
                          return Html::a(Html::encode( $model->sample_number), 
                          Url::to(['controller/action', 'sample_number' => $model->sample_number]));
                      },
 'format' => 'raw',     
 'options'=>['class'=>'success','style'=>'font-weight:bold;'],
],
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below code.

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'rowOptions'   => function ($model, $index, $widget, $grid) {

    return [
    'id' => $model['id'], 
    'onclick' => 'location.href="'
    . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('controllerName/view') 
    . '?id="+(this.id);'
    ];
    },
    ...
])
```

Comment: That does not look like valid PHP code. Can you highlight the parts that are crucial to solve the original problem?